# My random file php script isn't working right

Tags: php

So I have this php script that will by random display files from a certain directory and for me it's not working :/ the page just shows up blank even tho I uploaded html files to the directory, here's the script I used:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);


  function is_image($string){
    return ((file_exists($string))&&(preg_match('#(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png|\.bmp)$#i',$string)))  ? true : false ;
  }

  function is_text($string){
    return ((file_exists($string))&&(preg_match('#(\.txt|\.php|\.html)$#i',$string)))  ? true : false ;
  }

  define('OUTPUT_TYPE','html');
  define('RANDOM_FILES_FOLDER','randomstuff/');

  $my_array = Array();
  $my_dir = RANDOM_FILES_FOLDER ;

  if ($dir = @opendir("$my_dir")) {

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != ".."  && !is_dir($my_dir.$file))
      {
        switch(OUTPUT_TYPE):

          case'image':
            if(is_image($my_dir.$file)){
              $my_array[] = $file;
            }
          break;

          case'text':
            if(is_text($my_dir.$file)){
              $my_array[] = $file;
            }
          break;

          default:
          break;

        endswitch;

      }
    }
    closedir($dir);
  }


  if(count($my_array)>0){

    $random_number = rand(0, count($my_array)-1);
    $random_file = $my_array[$random_number];

    switch(OUTPUT_TYPE):

      case'image':   
        echo "<img src=\"".$my_dir.$random_file."\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\">";
      break;

      case'text':  
        include($my_dir.$random_file);
      break;

      default:
      break;

    endswitch;

  }
?>
```

your help will be appreciated

EDIT: my .htaccess file is causing the problem but I don't know how to fix it :( here's my .htaccess file:

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: What does your error log show?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a syntax problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Let me go check the error log brb @chris85

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I know why it's doing this now :/

Comment: it's doing this cause of my .htaccess file -_-

Comment: but I don't know how to fix it ;(

Comment: `cond ? true : false` is pretty same to just `cond`

Comment: update your question and add you .htaccess file to it

Comment: Try to remove `@` in `@opendir` for get actual error message.

Comment: @vp_arth removed the @ lemme test it now

Comment: @vp_arth removed the @ and it's still blank :/

Comment: Your `OUTPUT_TYPE` is const with `"html"` value. Why you `switch` it?

Comment: I'm so confused D:

Comment: @RyanVincent no, we haven't met before :/ I'm new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should do what first  `switch(OUTPUT_TYPE):`???

check file type before it

Comment: `$ftype = (is_image($file)) ? 'image' : 'text';`

`switch($ftype):`

Comment: where do I put that exactly? Edit: nvm

Comment: when I add `$ftype = (is_image($file)) ? 'image' : 'text'; switch($ftype):` then it makes the page unavailable

Comment: and replace include($my_dir.$random_file); to echo file_get_contents($my_dir.$random_file);

Comment: thanks! that worked the one where you put in the pastebin!

Comment: How? Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow @RyanVincent